# How to use ctime to mark starting and ending point of the program?

Tags: c++, ctime

```
time_t start;
time_t no_infection;
bool time_already_set = 0;
bool infected_or_not = 0;
int not_infected_t = 0;
```

I have this variables in struct and I want to mark starting and ending point of the objects, than calculate the difference.

```
void bacteria::set_no_infection() {
    if (infected_or_not == 0) 
        no_infection = clock();
}
```

For the start I have

```
void bacteria::set_time() {
    if (infected_or_not == 1 && time_already_set!=1) {
        start = clock();
        time_already_set = 1;
    }
}
```

It seems that time variables do not change during the program I test it using get functions

```
double bacteria::get_time() {
    if (infected_or_not == 1)  
        return ((clock() - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    else
        return -1;
}
int bacteria::get_no_infection() {
    if (infected_or_not = 0)   
        return ((clock() - no_infection) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    else
        return -1;
}
```

In main program I test it like this:

```
while (1) {
    for (int i = 0; i < b.size() - 1; i++) {
        bactpop[i].set_no_infection();
        bactpop[i].inf(phagepop[i], bactpop[i], p);
        bactpop[i].kill_the_bacteria(b, i);
        cout << "        " << b[i].start << "    " << b[i].no_infection << endl;
    }
    cout << p.size() << " " << b.size() << endl;
}
```

Comment: in a main program i test it like this: 

while (1) {
  for (int i = 0; i < b.size() - 1; i++) {
   bactpop[i].set_no_infection();
   bactpop[i].inf(phagepop[i], bactpop[i], p);
   bactpop[i].kill_the_bacteria(b, i);
   cout << "        " << b[i].start << "    "<<b[i].no_infection << endl;
  }
  cout << p.size() << " " << b.size() << endl;
 }

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but I guess your functions are called several times per second and since clock() / CLOCKS_PER_SEC returns values in seconds the differences will be 0 since the calls are executed in the same second.

Use for example gettimeofday which has microseconds or std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() if using C++11 is okay.